# Recover file after accidental truncating

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, data-recovery

I was trying to make some backup's and I accidentally started copying the backed up file OVER the current file; when I realized this I hit cancel only to see that my original 30 GB file had been deleted (I'm assuming because of how the Windows copy operation works on large files).

I used Zero Assumption Recovery, EasyRecover Pro and GetBackData; all I was able to see was that the file was deleted from the drive but it's being reported as 0 bytes. I know the size was EXACTLY 30 GB, if I did a little math I could come up with the sectors that this file resided on; is there a way I can recover my 30 GB delete file by specifying the RAW HDD sectors it was on, or does anyone know of recovery software that can potentially recover (find) this file?

If my question is unclear please let me know and I can edit.

Comment: Have you stopped working on that drive? STOP.

Comment: @Raystafarian is correct. If you continue running the OS, or writing to the disk, it could easily overwrite all or portions of that 30 GB file, especially if your hard drive has a small capacity.

Comment: LOL! Yeah, I stopped as soon as I realized it .. it's a secondary drive so the OS only touches it when I do .. I'm thinking druciferre is right about me having to search for it byte-by-byte :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a hex editor such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to read raw data from the hard drive.

Comment: didn't think of that! I'll see what that might get me

Comment: If you know portions of your file byte by byte, you can also search the hard drive, but it may take quite some time depending on the size of your hard drive.

Comment: 2 hours left .. :/ worst case scenario I'll just recover my 3 month old backup ... thanks for the help with HxD

Comment: Wouldn't the backup be easier if you have that available?

Comment: It's an encrypted TrueCrypt container, so the backup would be easier but the few additions I've made to it I don't have on my backup :/